# How to sum values in a spreadsheet based on matching criteria in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet where I track income and expenses. The spreadsheet has two different sheets which I am trying to craft a query between (example tables below).

**Transactions:**

[image]

**Categories:**

[image]

The goal of my query is to find the sum of the amount for each transaction that happened in a particular date range and where the associated category is of type "Expense".

I understand the basics of using SUMIF on the transactions using the date range as the criteria. What I can't figure out is how I would add "and the category ID matches the ID of a category on the other sheet who's type is 'Expense' ".

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you open to pivots?

Comment: I was hoping to accomplish it via queries since this value is being shown on a dashboard sheet I am creating where I want to control the UI highly.

Comment: I dont know any way of doing this without having an Type vlookup in the transactions table. If you want that i can post an answer.

Comment: Can you just hard code the *CategoryID*'s or do you need the equivalent of a SQL's *where categoryid in (select categoryid from categories where type like 'expense'* ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to hard code (i.e.type) the CategoryIDs into the formula then you just need a SUM wrapper around a SUMIFS.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Transactions!B:B, Transactions!C:C, {2,3,4,5}))
```

If you want to create an array of CategoryIDs based on the type then you need an array formula.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Transactions!B:B, Transactions!C:C, IF(Categories!D2:D8="expense", Categories!A2:A8)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.

Comment: I'm trying to use your dynamic solution using Array Forumlas in google sheets - what seems to be happening is it sums the transactions only for the very first category it finds that matches type=Expense instead of all where type=expense. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Here is how I have adapted the query to match my real table instead of my example above:
`=ArrayFormula(SUM(SUMIFS(Transactions!E:E, Transactions!D:D, IF(Categories!C2:C100="Expense", Categories!A2:A100))))`

Transactions!E = Amount, Transactions!D = Category, Categories!C = Type, Categories!A = Category